# How can I add test data to retrieve stocks transactions?

Tags: yodlee

I'm testing  the

https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest

endpoint using the sandbox. And I'm able to retrieve all the data; but for the project that I'm working on I need to test mostly with "stocks" data; when I set the data type to "stocks" I get 0 results.

How can I test that? or, maybe, how can I add stocks test data?

Thanks,
JD

Answer (score 0):

For getting stocks transaction you need to have a investment account aggregated which have stocks and transactions. You could use the Dummy Account Generator(DAG) tool to test this. Here is the [link](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Sample_Data/Yodlee_Dummy_Account_Generator) about how to use DAG.

Once you create a DAG catalog you can use it as it is or even edit the data or number of transactions present in it(in form of XML) and upload the edited XML to the DAG and then  add the site within your Test user account in sandbox.

Using executeUserSearchRequest API you will get the transactions either for all containers or specifically for stocks. But you need to have a test account added to retrieve the transactions.